# VISUAL C# - WPF Page Name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

in short, I need to be able to automatically create a number "tot" of pages in my project, each page should have a different name, and for this reason, I need a method that gives me the opportunity to define the name of each page dynamically at the time of declaration.

Right now, not being able to find a solution, I propose the creation code of 2 pages I created:

```
Page fisrt= new Page();
Page second= new Page();
```

when in fact I would need to:

```
for (int i=0; i<tot; ++i)
{
 Page nome = new Page();
}
```

Term "name" in the code that I pasted,  will be the page name that dynamic will change every time, for example from a table in a DB, but then that will be something that I'll see later.

If instead of "name" I enter a string or variable name of a string variable this isn't work!
So I just need to know what is the only way to create each page with a different name every time.

Thank you very much! =)

Comment: Can't you put them in some collection? :-)

Comment: Hi, 
sure, but, if i wrote in the forum this means that i'm not able to edit a solution that work fine.
i'm tried to use dictionary int this way:

Dictionary<Int32, Page> dictionary = new Dictionary<Int32, Page>

for(int i=0; i<tot; ++1)
{
dictionary.Add(i, i.Tostring());
Page dictionary[i]= new Page();
}


Is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your pages in a collection. If you want get a reference via a string you could use a SortedList<> for example:

```
SortedList<string, Page> pageList = new SortedList<string, Page>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    pageList.Add(string.Format("Page{0}", i), new Page());
}
```

You can then get a reference to a specific page like so:

```
Page page = pageList["Page2"];
```

or

```
pageList["Page0"].ActualHeight = 250;
```